# Displaying checkbox dynamically in PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, display

A benefit can be assigned to an employee but firstly the code below shows the dynamic dropdown of employee and dynamic benefit checkboxes

```
<?php
  $ctr = 0;
  $employee = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM housekeeping_employee") or DIE("Could not Select");
  echo  "<select class='indent' name = 'Employee'>";
  while($listEmployee = mysqli_fetch_array($employee))
  {
    echo "<option value = ".$listEmployee['employeeid'].">".$listEmployee['firstname']."</option>";
  }
  echo  "</select>";
  echo    "<br><be>";
  echo    "<div class='indent'>";
  $benefits = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM housekeeping_benefit")or DIE("SELECT Query not working.");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($benefits))
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($benefits))
    {
      $ctr++;
      echo "<h6><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'benefits".$ctr."' value ='".$row['benefitid']."' >".$row['benefitname']." </input></h6> <be>";
      if($ctr == 5){
        echo"<br>";
        $ctr=0;
      }
    }
    echo "<br><input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='insert' value='Submit'/>";
  }
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='ctr' value='".$ctr."'/>";
  echo "</form>";
?>
```

This is what the insert code of assigning benefits to employee looks like.

```
$employeeid = $_POST['Employee'];
for($a = 1; $a <= $_POST['ctr'] ; $a++)
{
  if(isset($_POST['benefits'.$a]))
  {
    $benefitid = $_POST['benefits'.$a];
    //echo "INSERT INTO `housekeeping_employeebenefits`(`employeeid`,`benefitid`) VALUES('$employeeid','$benefitid')";
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `housekeeping_employeebenefits`(`employeeid`,`benefitid`) VALUES('$employeeid','$benefitid')") or DIE("Insert query is not working");
    echo "Employee to Benefits successful!";
  }
}
```

My main problem is how will I display checked checkboxes if the employee already has that benefit? I'm really lost